# How to ignore the focus of a cell in gridfieldmanager?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i just made this example for the sake of my question.

```java
public MyScreen()
{       
    setTitle("GridFieldManager");
    GridFieldManager grid2 = new GridFieldManager(1,2,GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE);

    add(grid2);

    String[] choice={"1","2","0"};
    ObjectChoiceField menu=new ObjectChoiceField(null,choice);

    //grid.add(lol);
    grid2.add(new LabelField("Productos_",NON_FOCUSABLE));
    grid2.add(menu);
}
```

For some reason i still can focus the labelfield even when i said it was non focusable (`Field.NON_FOCUSABLE`).

Note: Just to let you know, i'm using a label + objectchoicefield so i can have total control of the properties of that label, since i found troublesome changing the color and font from the label that objectchoicefield has.

In this picture you can see how the focus is on the `LabelField`. i just want to focus the objectchoicefield list.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, to me, this seems like a bug.  I don't think it should work this way.  However, at this point, nothing in older BlackBerry Java devices is going to be fixed, so we just have to work around it.

The problem is that you have set your `LabelField` to be non-focusable, but the device is ignoring that.  It is opening your screen with focus on the `GridFieldManager`, which just puts focus on its first field (the label).  If the user moves focus onto the choice field, you won't be able to get focus **back** to the label field.  But, I'm sure you don't want the screen opening with focus on something non-focusable.

You can either just set focus manually to the choice field:

```java
  //grid.add(lol);
  grid2.add(new LabelField("Productos_", NON_FOCUSABLE));
  grid2.add(menu);  

  menu.setFocus();
```

or, if you want to handle this more generically, you can write your own method to initialize the focus to the first field that's really focusable:

```java
public class LabelFocusScreen extends MainScreen {

   public LabelFocusScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      setTitle("GridFieldManager");
      GridFieldManager grid2 = new GridFieldManager(1,2,GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE);

      add(grid2);


      String[] choice={"1","2","0"};
      ObjectChoiceField menu=new ObjectChoiceField(null,choice);

      //grid.add(lol);
      grid2.add(new LabelField("Productos_", NON_FOCUSABLE));
      grid2.add(menu);  

      initializeFocus(this);
   }

   /** @return true if focus was set within the given field */
   private boolean initializeFocus(Field f) {
      boolean focusSet = false;
      if (f instanceof Manager) {
         Manager m = (Manager)f;
         // loop over all child fields, recursively
         for (int i = 0; i < m.getFieldCount(); i++) {
            if (initializeFocus(m.getField(i))) {
               focusSet = true;
               break;
            }
         }
      } else if (f.isFocusable()) {
         f.setFocus();
         focusSet = true;
      }
      return focusSet;
   }
}
```

Both solutions should work for you.

*Note: by the way, you don't have to actually set the `LabelField` to be non-focusable.  It will be non-focusable by default.  It doesn't hurt.  It's just not needed.*

---

### Update:

If you also want to be able to set focus back to `grid2` later (after the screen first appears), you can also call my `initializeFocus()` method again, to prevent any more problems with the non-focusable label gaining focus.

For example, make your screen `implement FocusChangeListener`, and then in its constructor:

```java
  grid2.add(new LabelField("Productos_", NON_FOCUSABLE));
  grid2.add(menu); 
  grid2.setFocusListener(this);
```

where the focus listener implementation includes this new method (in your screen class):

```java
public void focusChanged(Field f, int event) {
   if (event == FocusChangeListener.FOCUS_GAINED) {
      initializeFocus(f);
   }
}
```

This will allow `initializeFocus()` to be called for the `grid2` manager object, if focus is later set back to it.  Calling `initializeFocus()`, passing the grid field manager as the argument, will correctly set focus to its first *focusable* field.

Comment: hello sorry for taking so long to answer wasn't able to work. So what if i have 2 grids for example when i come back to the first grid the focus will be on the label field again. I think i need a focuslistener so i can set the focus to other field when this field has it or rewrite the "first focusable field" , is there a way to this ?

Comment: @AmirG, I have updated my answer to handle this case.  Basically, you do just add a focus change listener, and then have that listener call my `initializeFocus()` method for the grid field, to use the logic that searches for the first focusable field.  I tested this, and it worked for me.

Comment: Thnx @Nate awesome as always